# Changing the name of a specific position

Tags: r

I had defined a numerical vector as -

```
X <- c(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

Now, I want to change name ‘b’ in the second position to ‘z’.

When I use the command

```
names(X[2]) <- "z"
```

it does not work.

But, when I use

```
names(X)[2] <- "z"
```

it does work

Why this behaviour & what is the difference between the above two `names()` approaches?

Comment: In the first case you extract `X[2]`, creating a temporary vector, then get the `names` of that temp vector. The vector is temporary because it only exists inside the `names()` call. And that vector's names, only one name btw, is what you change. In the second case you get the names of the actual vector `X` and change its second element. You are accessing `X`, not a temp copy.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `help("names")`, you see that two usages are listed:

```
names(x)
names(x) <- value
```

So, there is both an getter and setter functionality defined. And the intended usages is your second approach.

The simplified reason why your first approach does not work is that `X[2]` returns

```
 #b 
 #2
```

I.e. a named vector of length 1. Hence, doing

```
 names(X[2]) <- "z"
```

will rename, but the result is never saved.